# Customizing django.contrib.comments

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-comments

The customization that `django.contrib.comments` on django v1.4.5 (I know its deprecated on future versions) is quite low. Moderation is quite customizable..

Right now, the preview and error page for comment POST request land on new page. Redirection is only through an hidden input value for correct inputs!! Is there anyway to customize this module and provide preview on the same page, show success message on the same page? Am I missing anything in docs?

Or I have only option to go through the existing code in django.contrib.comments module and override specific methods in my local module?? --This is not good for code reusability

Comment: Did you manage to do it?

Comment: yes, I customized a lot more changes

Comment: Would you like sharing your solution with us please,specialy handling the error